# non pod structs behavior with extern C

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

Consider this code:

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  virtual std::string speak() = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base {
  std::string speak() override { return "Speaking"; }
};

extern "C" {
std::unique_ptr<Base> make() {
  return std::make_unique<Derived>();
}
}
```

Compiling this code with [clang](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/732f27b903393535) gives the following warning:

```
main.cpp:13:23: warning: 'make' has C-linkage specified, but returns incomplete type 'std::unique_ptr<Base>' which could be incompatible with C [-Wreturn-type-c-linkage]
std::unique_ptr<Base> make() {
                      ^
1 warning generated.
```

[gcc](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22aac4088f9cd092) doesn't generate this warning.

Since standard doesn't require compilers to generate warnings for all cases, I think gcc is correct within its own right for not producing a warning.

My question is - If I intent to use `make` function in a C++ file while `dlopen/dlsym`, am I breaking any rules of the standard by using a non-pod return value?

Comment: You can't use C++ classes in C.  Having `make()` return a `unique_ptr` makes no sense if `make()` is ever going to be used in C code. Otherwise why wrap it in `extern "C"`? Also, it is not safe to use classes across compiler boundaries, so if `make()` is going to be exported from a library shared with other compilers, returning a `unique_ptr` still doesn't make sense to do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am less concerned about other compilers, and I don't plan to use C. I do plan to use shared libraries and the usage of 'extern C' is to avoid name mangling such that `dlsym` can correctly find the symbol.

Comment: Instead of `extern "C"` you can use pragma `__asm__("actualname")` to rename your function.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is - If I intent to use make function in a C++ file while dlopen/dlsym, am I breaking any rules of the standard by using a non-pod return value?

No. You aren't breaking any rules of the C++ standard.